# Failed to combine array of object react native

Tags: react-native, google-cloud-firestore

Im trying to join the data into the existing array of oject in state. in console.log(data) i get the data as expected but its not join together with this.state.listData.

"react-native": "0.61.5",
"@react-native-firebase/firestore": "^6.3.4",

```
retrieveMore = async () => {
        const { navigation }  = this.props;
        const title2 = navigation.getParam('title2', null);
        userEmail = firebase.auth().currentUser.email;
        try {

                const data = [];
                await database.collection("All Recipes").orderBy("reviewCount", "desc").startAfter(this.state.lastVisible).limit(this.state.limit).get().then(doc => {
                    doc.forEach( async (doc) =>{
                        const {filter, id , name, image} = doc.data();
                        lastVisible = doc;
                        let recipeId = doc.data().id;
                        let test = await database.collection("All Recipes").doc(recipeId).collection("Reviews").onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {
                            let data2 = [];
                            querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                                const { Rating } = doc.data();
                                data2.push({
                                    Rating: Rating,
                                });
                            });
                            const totalRating = data2.reduce((prev,next) => prev + next.Rating,0);
                            let averageRating = parseInt((Math.round(totalRating/data2.length * 100) / 100).toFixed(1));
                            let totalReview = Math.abs(data2.length) > 999 ? Math.sign(data2.length)*((Math.abs(data2.length)/1000).toFixed(1)) + 'k' : Math.sign(data2.length)*Math.abs(data2.length);

                            data.push({
                                filter: filter,
                                id:id,
                                name:name,
                                image:image,
                                averageRating: averageRating,
                                totalReview: totalReview,
                            });
                        });
                    });
                    console.log(data);
                    this.setState({
                      listData:[...this.state.listData, ...data],
                      lastVisible: lastVisible,
                      loading: false,
                    });
                })

        }
        catch (error) {
          console.log(error);
        }
      };
```

if i commented the the code like below,the data and the this.state.listData join perfectly but without averageRating and totalReview.

```
const data = [];
                await database.collection("All Recipes").orderBy("reviewCount", "desc").startAfter(this.state.lastVisible).limit(this.state.limit).get().then(doc => {
                    doc.forEach( async (doc) =>{
                        const {filter, id , name, image} = doc.data();
                        lastVisible = doc;
                        let recipeId = doc.data().id;
                        // let test = await database.collection("All Recipes").doc(recipeId).collection("Reviews").onSnapshot(function(querySnapshot) {
                        //     let data2 = [];
                        //     querySnapshot.forEach(function(doc) {
                        //         const { Rating } = doc.data();
                        //         data2.push({
                        //          Rating: Rating,
                        //          });
                        //     });
                        //     const totalRating = data2.reduce((prev,next) => prev + next.Rating,0);
                        //  let averageRating = parseInt((Math.round(totalRating/data2.length * 100) / 100).toFixed(1));
                        //  let totalReview = Math.abs(data2.length) > 999 ? Math.sign(data2.length)*((Math.abs(data2.length)/1000).toFixed(1)) + 'k' : Math.sign(data2.length)*Math.abs(data2.length);

                            data.push({
                                filter: filter,
                                id:id,
                                name:name,
                                image:image,
                               //  averageRating: averageRating,
                                // totalReview: totalReview,
                            });
                        });
                    // });
                    console.log(data);
                    this.setState({
                      listData:[...this.state.listData, ...data],
                      lastVisible: lastVisible,
                      loading: false,
                    });
                })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
this.setState(state=>({
    listData:[...state.listData, ...data],
    lastVisible: lastVisible,
    loading: false,
}));
```

try this it may help you

Comment: the answer still same.. i still cant figured out what cause the problem.. when i commend the second firestore call its join perfectly but not the result i want